# ec2-aws create-volume & attach-volume script

Tags: ruby, bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to make a ruby script to attach an EBS volume in AWS EC2. I'm missing some minor detail because I got an error at attaching the volume. Please see the error below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'rubygems'

cmd = "ec2-create-volume  --size 10 --region us-east-1 --availability-zone us-east-1a --type gp2"
system(cmd, :out => ['/tmp/volid', 'w'])
volid = `awk '{print $2}' /tmp/volid`
puts "#{volid}"     ----->  PUTS THE VARIABLE AS EXPECTED

cmd = "ec2-attach-volume #{volid} --instance i-2e69a1b5 --device /dev/xvdg"
system(cmd)  ---->  It shows ERROR -i instance/--instance is missing, somehow is putting the variable incorectly, it's like is not reading the command after the volid variable.
```

If I declare up voldid = 'vol-123' the script is working but if I put it from a file is not working even if output it shows vol-123.

Answer (score 1):

At guess there is a end of line character at the end of the file you are reading the volume id from. The `strip` function removes leading and trailing whitespace which should clear this up.

It also seems like it would be easier to do

```
volid = File.read("/tmp/volid").strip
```

Rather than shelling out to awk. You can also avoid the use of a temporary file altogether by using one the various method that allow you to capture command output (backticks, popen, open3 etc). The aws ruby sdk is also pretty easy to use, although that is obviously a different kettle of fish.